# Is there a short proof for Bézout's lemma when $\gcd(a,b)=1$?

Tags: diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

Bézout's lemma states that there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that

$$ax+by=\gcd(a,b)$$

Is there some short proof for this when $a$ and $b$ are coprime? As opposed to something like [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_Lemma), like, from an algebraic/ring theoretic perspective.

Comment: The length of the proof is mostly determined by what sort of things you're willing to take for granted already. If you know the division algorithm the proof is very short. The relevant algebraic setup is not group theory but ring theory; look up principal ideal domains, GCD domains, and Bezout domains.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan With division algorithm you are referring to Euclid's?